# Unexpected white gaps between divs, only in google chrome

Tags: css, whitespace

There are some white gaps appearing between divs, but only in google chrome and only on certain res. The problem is displayed in the image. Any ideas?

[image]

```
.container{
margin: 0;
max-width: 136rem; 
height: 80%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
position: relative;
}

.item{
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .7s;
 color: var(--color-4);
 min-height: 8rem;
flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/janvzku2/2/
i put some of the code here and there is the same problem between some divs. But only i chrome.

Comment: Please share your code snippet

Comment: can you please share your code it would be helpful

Comment: is it ok to post your website (where the problem is) link here?

Comment: It's better if you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/janvzku2/2/
if you open this in chrome, there is a white gap between some sections/divs, but in mozila or safari it is all good. Any ideas?